# Como saber si un objeto es un string

Tags: javascript, string, extjs

Cuando doy doble click en la [celda](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-event-celldblclick) de una grid de ExtJs me retorna el uuid pero al seleccionar el botón me retorna el objeto como tal.

¿Cómo puedo saber si lo que me retorna es un string o un objeto?

Comment: Usted debe incluir el código para poder ayudarte y buscar una solución.

Comment: @Bany Alvarado Bienvenido a SOes. Para poder contestar a tus preguntas debes postear siempre el código relevante de tu aplicación o al menos algo que nos ayude a reproducir tu problema para poder ayudarte a darle solución. Lee mas sobre como crear un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y [cómo preguntar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ¿La grid en dónde está? ¿Cuál botón seleccionas? ¿De qué objeto hablas? El título indica una cosa pero el cuerpo de la pregunta es totalmente descabellado y difícil de entender. Si fuese solo por el título, votaría para re abrir la pregunta. Pero ante un mal cuerpo, luce como una mala pregunta. Favor de editarlo para comprender mejor lo que necesitas saber.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En javascript la forma más segura de saber si es un objeto de tipo x lo puedes hacer con `Object.prototype.toString` ya que este te dará un resultado como `[object Tipo]`.

Esta solución puede que no te funcione para el objeto ya que este puede devolverte `[object Object]` u otra cosa dependiendo de la forma como lo hayan implementado.

Si te funcionará para los `strings` ya que siempre devolverá `[object String]` asi que puedes usar la siguiente función.

```
function isString(obj) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object String]';
}
```

Puedes usar `typeof` también pero no te lo recomiendo ya que

```
 console.log(typeof 'sdas');               => string
 console.log(typeof new String('sdas'));   => object
```

Comment: Respuestas similares a esta ya existen en [¿Cómo diferenciar entre un objeto y un arreglo en JavaScript?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/450/c%C3%B3mo-diferenciar-entre-un-objeto-y-un-arreglo-en-javascript)

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Cierto pero en este caso saber si es un objeto no tiene mucho sentido ya que lo que se desea es saber si es un `string` ya que el extjs devuelve un objeto o un nombre. La respuesta que refieres puede servir pero la solución no será obvia para alguien nuevo en el lenguaje javascript.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz por cierto la respuesta que refieres esta bien pero no es 100% correcta ya que al llamar Object.prototype.toString.call en un elemento html, ej un div te dará algo como [object HTMLDivElement], tu asumes en los comentarios que esta funcion solo aplica a los objetos como Array, Arguments, etc. Es por eso que en esta pregunta probar si es un objeto no es 100% conclusivo, depende de la implementación. No obstante, muy buena respuesta ;)